# Should two dependent features be included in the training set of a classification model?

Tags: machine-learning

I have just started the data science journey so please pardon me if the question is silly. If in a dataset there are two columns which are dependent on each other like 'fare' and 'type_of_seat'. So, should we include both the features in the training set or including only one of them will do the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How strong is the dependency? Put another way, do you gain any information by including both features? If one can be directly computed from the other (as in your example, I suspect fare can be directly inferred from type_of_seat) then you don't gain anything and can leave one of the features out, since they are redundant.